# show/hide div on click with JS and introduction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to the front-end web developing sphere and I have only studied HTML/CSS for ~ a month and a half and just about 1 week or less into JS. Since I want to practice what I learn from different websites I make my own to test my knowledge. I want to apologize in advance if I am asking too many questions, but there aren't any people I know that I can share coding issues with.

So I wanted to make ( just for testing ) a show/hide div which is activated when you click a button with JS. I can make it show, but I wanted to try to make it hide/show with an "if/else" function. I thought my code was right but it doesn't seem to work and I can't find a solution. I'll share with you my code ( the part of it which I have problems with actually) and will be very grateful if you can help me find a solution.

HTML :

```
<button type="button" onclick="slide()" >Click Me</button>
<div class="divtest" id="dropdown">   
<span>If you are seeing this, then your JS worked! </span>
</div>
```

The CSS ( some things are pointless, I just added them in to test a bit ):

```
.divtest {
position: absolute;
left: 25%;
bottom: 30px;
width: 50%;
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
box-sizing: border-box;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 3px;
text-align: center;
padding: 40px;
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Cooper, sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;    
transition:  1s ease;
background-color: limegreen;
color: black;
display: none;
}

button {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
left: 25%;
bottom: 130px;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid black;
background-color: limegreen;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 3px;
color: black;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Cooper, sans-serif;
font-weight: 100; 

}
```

the JS:

```
<script>
function slide() {
    var drop = document.getElementById("dropdown"); // declares the element with id="dropdown" as a var
    var dropSetting = drop.style.display;  // declares that the variable "drop"'s display property is also a variable
    if (dropSetting == "none") {  // if the current value of display = "none" ( which it is as u can see in the CSS)
        dropSetting == "block";   // Then set it to "block" 
    }
    else {                                    // if the value of display != none
        dropSetting == "none";   // then set it to "none"
    }
}

</script>
```

If you have any questions towards the code or anything, please feel free to ask as this is a separate feature contained in my test website so it is not connected in any way to other elements/attributes. I tried this code first in another way (without declaring dropSetting as a var, just adding in a few lines in the if/else function ) but it still did not work.I don't think JS recognizes the "style.display" as a property because Brackets doesn't highlight it. Thank you very much for your time in advance, and I hope that soon I too will be able to help some people out with what I know!

Also - a side question - What are your thoughts on treehouse? I have heard very good things about them and I'm thinking about signing up to further my knowledge.

Have a nice day!

Comment: You typo'd inside your `if` and `else`. It should be `dropSetting = "block";` or `dropSetting = "none";` (only 1 = sign).

Answer (score 1):

For code compatibility, try to use methods, no shortcuts, for attributes use:

```
var drop = document.getElementById("dropdown"); 
drop.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
var display = drop.getAttribute('display'); //Here is all the inline css, better do like below:
```

And it is much better for a clean and faster code, make all css clases you need:

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
drop.classList.add('hide');
drop.classList.remove('hide');
drop.classList.toggle('hide');
```

Never used Treehouse, but for myself the best teacher is a good IDE for web like Atom of VScode, google Chrome console (F12), and those are your books:

-http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp

-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

And this is your teacher for questions:
 stackoverflow.com

You dont need anything more.

PD: Your logic is ok, just don't get used to code shortcuts, they may not work in all environments. (like elem.attribute instead of elem.getAttribute(''))

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't works because you didn't assign display property to appropriate value (block / none). you have used comparison operator("==") instead of equals ("=").

```
 if (dropSetting == "none") {  // if the current value of display = "none" ( which it is as u can see in the CSS)
    dropSetting = "block";   // Then set it to "block" 
}
else {                                    // if the value of display != none
    dropSetting = "none";   // then set it to "none"
}
```

"==" operator in your code will just return true/false without changing display property of the div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your dropSetting is *not* an object, just string. When you change it (if change) you don't change the object (style in this case). Try something like this:

```
var drop = document.getElementById("dropdown"); //get reference to the object
drop.style.display = drop.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'; //if(...){do something}else{do something else}
```

Another possibility:

```
var dropStyle = document.getElementById("dropdown").style; 
if(dropStyle.display == 'none'){
    dropStyle.display = 'block';
}else
    dropStyle.display = 'none';
```